# Properties of integration a delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I have great difficulties understanding why the following relation holds:

$$\int^{t}_{0} \int^{t’}_{0}\delta(t_1-t_2)\mathrm{d}t_1\mathrm{d}t_2=\min\{t,t’\}.$$

Our teacher gave us an explanation involving geometry which I am unable to reproduce. I tried to used the integral representation of the delta function but get non convergent results. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Regarding the $t^* = \min\{t, t'\}$, if you draw the region of integration and the straight line $t_1=t_2$ you'll see  that if $t_1 >t^*$ or $t_2>t^*$ the straight line $t_1=t_2$ (where $\delta \ne 0$) does not cross the integration region and so
$$
\int_0^t \int_0^{t'} \delta(t_1-t_2) dt_1 dt_2 = \int_0^{t^*} \int_0^{t^*} \delta(t_1-t_2) dt_1 dt_2.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate out $t_1$ first to get $\int_0^t[t_2\in(0,\,t^\prime)] dt_2$, where for any proposition $p$ the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) $[p]$ is $1$ if $p$ is true or $0$ if $p$ is false. This single integral is $\int_{[0,\,t]\cap[0,\,t^\prime]}1 dt_2=\min\{t,\,t^\prime\}$.